# Should I manually fix the distribution entry after OS upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, software-sources

I have upgraded to 13.04 with `do-release-upgrade`. During the upgrade, most of the repository sources will be disabled.

Now that the upgrade is finished, and while looking which of them I want enabled, I noticed that some of them still have an older distribution in their entry. And some of them have `raring`.

I am wondering if I should

1. Manually change them to `raring`
2. Not bother and enable them as is
3. Not enable them at all

Which is safer and/or better action to do in this case?

**Example of a source auto-updated to raring:**
[image: Example of a source auto-updated to raring]

**Example of a source still using precise:**
[image: Example of a source still using precise]

Comment: Mark as duplicate. Then we know that there is a similar problem for 13.04 as well as 12.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Good find @dan :) You can delete your own question if you want. Or wait for 3 downvotes and get the peer pressure badge >:D Or wait for 5 close votes

Comment: @Ads20000 problem... you can only dupe when it has an accepted or upvoted answer ;) edit: Now we can :D